# How to get started with Storm-crawler

Tags: maven, web-crawler, stormcrawler

I'm trying to get started with [Storm-crawler](http://stormcrawler.net) but am a bit confused when it comes to Maven, not too familiar with Maven. Do I just simply clone the github repo for [Storm-crawler](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler), cd into that and then run mvn clean install?

OR do I mkdir storm-crawler, cd into that and run all those maven commands that are on the stormcrawler.net getting-started page? Will maven download everything I need and after that how do I run Storm-crawler.

Storm-crawler looks really cool, but Maven is brand new to me... (I'm familiar with npm - and they keep it simple!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to use the latest code which has not yet been released, there is no need to build SC. Just run the archetype command and it will build a proto project for you which will have the StormCrawler dependencies already configured. Maven will download everything indeed. Look at the README that will be in the generated project for instructions on how to run it.

What you described in the first paragraph is how to compile SC itself, which shouldn't be needed. The latest version will be downloaded by Maven.

See [WIKI](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/Presentations) for a list of tutorial and resources

Comment: awesome - thanks, got things going. I'm looking at the ES setup you have and it looks like I can setup an SC based project with ES by simply replacing the -DarchetypeArtifactId with storm-crawler-elasticsearch, would that be correct?

Comment: one more thing, what version of ES do you recommend running 2.x or 5.x?

Comment: > replacing the -DarchetypeArtifactId with storm-crawler-elasticsearch, would that be correct?

no. look at the resources listed on the WIKI page above. There is a video tutorial on how to set up SC with ES. It will show you step by step.

>  2.x or 5.x?

SC 1.5 will be based on ES 5.x but has not yet been released. The tutorial I mentioned is based on 2.x, maybe use that first while you get familiar with SC.